# Programmatically assign then trigger control event handler

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with several groups of controls and I want to be able to toggle enabled/disabled those groups individually with a Toggle Button control. When the form loads, I programmatically assign a UDF called `ToggleGroup` to each toggle button's `AfterUpdate()` event handler. I have tested this part of the code and know that it performs as intended.

I want the groups to start in a disabled state, so I want to trigger the `AfterUpdate()` handler for each toggle button after I assign the function. I know that I could achieve this in a few other ways (I could change the properties of the grouped controls in Design View or I could call `ToggleGroup` on them as part of the form's initialization), but for my own curiosity and interest, I want to know if the method I described is feasible.

```
'''GroupTags is a collection of all Tags associated with control groups
For Each iTag In GroupTags
    CtrlName = "Toggle_" & iTag

    Me(CtrlName).AfterUpdate = _
        "=ToggleGroup( ...valid arguments... )"

    '''Here: trigger the AfterUpdate event for this control based on CtrlName
Next iTag
```

Comment: Maybe with `CallByName`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661103/using-callbyname-with-an-event-sink-for-a-field-on-a-form

Comment: @Andre Alright, I tried `CallByName Me, CtrlName & "_AfterUpdate", vbMethod, Array(...valid arguements...)` and it didn't work. I think I'm just going to call `ToggleGroup` on its own and pass it `iTag`.